# Comparing vector of double

Tags: c++11, vector

I am trying to compare two vectors. 
v1 = {0.520974 , 0.438171 , 0.559061}
v2 = [0.520974 , 0.438171 , 0.559061}

I write v1 to a file, read and that's v2. For some reason when I compare the two vectors, I am getting false!

When I do: v1[0]-v2[0] I get 4.3123e-8

Thanks,

Comment: How are they in the file? As text, you'd have to be very careful to use a round-trip-safe conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double values, unlike integers, are fragile against write and read. That means, the information that represents them in a string is not necessarily complete.

The leading reason of that is rounding: it's like if you had 1/7 and wanted to write it on a paper in the same format as in your question, you'd get:

```
0.142857
```

That's exact to 6 decimal places, but no more than that, and the difference shows up. The only difference in the computer is that it counts in binary (and rounds in binary, too), and is further complicated by the fact that at output (or input) you coerce that into decimal (or back, respectively) and round *again* at each step. All of those are sources of little errors.

If you want to be able to save and reload your doubles exactly (on the same machine), do it in their native binary representation using a `write` and `read`. If you want them to be human-readable, you need to sacrifice the exact reconstruction. You'd then need to compare them up to a little allowed deviation.

Comment: Makes sense, I am now comparing the difference to a small margin and it works! Thank you!